# Passing value from p5 sketch to React (with react-p5-wrapper)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, p5.js

I have a p5 webcam video prediction system working right now. Currently, I'm trying to plug this into a React app to create a fuller web app.

My problem is, the prediction is now only made in my p5 sketch, I want the prediction value to be passed into React's App.js for further constructions. Is there any method of doing so?

I'm using react-p5-wrapper btw.

Here's the sketch.js:

```
import "react-p5-wrapper/node_modules/p5/lib/addons/p5.dom";
import ml5 from 'ml5';

let mobileNet;
let video;
let label='model loading...';

function sketch (p) {

    p.setup = function () {
        p.createCanvas(1000, 1000);
        //imitialize the webcam stream in a object
        video = p.createCapture(p.VIDEO);
        //hide the webcam stream
        video.hide();

        //initialize the mobilenet object with a callback
        mobileNet= ml5.imageClassifier('MobileNet',video,ModelLoaded);
    };

    p.draw = function () {
        p.image(video,0,0);
        p.textSize(16);
        p.fill(255,140,0);
        p.text(label,10,450);
    };
};

function ModelLoaded()
{
    console.log('Model is ready');
    //predicting the image
    mobileNet.predict(result)
}

//callback function to get the results
function result(err,res)
{
    //check for errors
    if(err)
    {
        //log the error if any
        console.error(err)
    }
    else{
        //get the label from the json result
        label = res[0].className;
    //predicting the image again
        mobileNet.predict(result)
    }
}


export default sketch;
```

And my App.js currently looks like this:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
// import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import sketch from './sketch';
import P5Wrapper from 'react-p5-wrapper';



class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount(){

  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">

        <P5Wrapper sketch={sketch} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I gave this a go and came up with a solution. It isn't very elegant but it should do. I made a very simple test project in sketch.js where I try to illustrate two ways accessing the infromation. The things to note are the *timesClicked* variable and the *updateWithProps* function.

```
export let timesClicked = 0;
export default function sketch (p) {

    p.setup = function () {
        p.createCanvas(300, 300);
    };

    p.draw = function () {
        p.background(0);
        p.fill(255);
        p.ellipse(p.mouseX, p.mouseY, 100, 100);
    };

    p.updateWithProps() = function(newProps){
        if(newProps.getCoords){
            p.sendCoords = newProps.getCoords;
        }
    }

    p.mouseClicked = function() {
        p.sendCoords(p.mouseX, p.mouseY);
        timesClicked++;
    }
};
```

*timesClicked* is a variable that can be imported and counts the times the mouse has been clicked. It can be modified from inside the sketch scope and imported from other files.

*updateWithProps* is a function called from the react-p5-wrapper library whenever the component receives *props* and can be defined inside the sketch.

With this, your App.js file could be modified like so:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import P5Wrapper from 'react-p5-wrapper';

import sketch from './sketch';

import {timesClicked} from './sketch';

function getCoords(){
    console.log(arguments);
}

class App extends Component {
    componentDidMount(){

    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <P5Wrapper sketch={sketch} getCoords={getCoords}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;

document.body.onkeyup = function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 32){
        console.log(timesClicked);
    }
}
```

When running, every time there is a click, the sketch will execute the *getCoords()* function in the App.js file and, alternatively, every time the space bar is pressed the *timesClicked* variable will be accessed from the App.js file. I think you can modify this in order to "send" or "read" the prediction value.

*Edited as per Daniel's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73294534/9653121)*

Answer (score 3):

Update from Julian's previous answer:
As of now (August 2022), `p.myCustomRedrawAccordingToNewPropsHandler()` has been renamed to `p.updateWithProps()`

Read more: https://github.com/P5-wrapper/react#props